# non-block TCP socket programming

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, nonblocking

I would like to make non-block TCP receiver so the cilent can send message to server periodically (i.e. update information every 10 minutes).

I test it in a local machine. 'return_status' value indicates that the 'bind, accept, connect and write' are working correctly but the read always return -1. Can someone explain on this? Thanks

Code of client side.

```
#define CONTROLPORT 6000

int main(void)
{

int control_sock, return_status;
struct sockaddr_in control_addr;
socklen_t control_len;
memset(&control_addr, 0, sizeof(control_addr));
char control_message[10];

control_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

control_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
control_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.16.133");
control_addr.sin_port = htons(CONTROLPORT);

return_status = bind(control_sock, (struct sockaddr *) &control_addr, sizeof(control_addr));

fcntl(control_sock, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK); 

return_status = listen(control_sock, 1);
    cout << return_status << endl;
return_status = accept(control_sock, (struct sockaddr *) &control_addr, &control_len); 
    cout << return_status << endl;

while(1){

    return_status = read(control_sock,control_message,sizeof(control_message));

    cout << return_status << endl;

}







}
```

Code of sender side

```
#define CONTROLPORT 6000

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{

int control_sock, return_status;
struct sockaddr_in control_addr;
socklen_t control_len;
memset(&control_addr, 0, sizeof(control_addr));
char control_message[10];
control_message[10] = 111;

control_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

control_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
control_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.16.133");
control_addr.sin_port = htons(CONTROLPORT);

return_status = connect(control_sock, (struct sockaddr *) &control_addr, sizeof(control_addr));
    cout << return_status << endl;



    return_status = write(control_sock,control_message,sizeof(control_message));

    cout << return_status << endl;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have set your socket to non-blocking and as such `accept` is not going to block until some one connects. `accept` would be returning EAGAIN or EQOULDBLOCK. Check the errno. Without this checks your code proceeds to do the `read`. And it returns -1 (again check the errno) since the connections has not been established in the first place.

You have to use `select`, `poll` or `epoll` to see for events on non blocking sockets. That is to figure out if someone is connecting /sending data on established connections.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I deleted the fcntl(control_sock, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);  The function "read' still return -1. At the mean while, the accept function returns 4. Seems like even I set it to blocking one, the problem remains exist.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, I don't think non-blocking server is necessary. If you really mean that, you should take a look at `select()`, `epoll` and the similar. As to your code, there're several problems:

1. `accept()` in the server side should be in the while loop.
2. `accept()` returns a descriptor for the accepted socket on success, and this descriptor should pass to `read()`.
3. As Prabhu's answer says, you have set your socket to `O_NONBLOCK`, so the `accept()` would return immediately. If no connections are present to be accepted, the `errno` would be set to `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`.

the code after modification:

```
int main(void)
{
    int control_sock, return_status;
    struct sockaddr_in control_addr;
    socklen_t control_len;
    memset(&control_addr, 0, sizeof(control_addr));
    char control_message[10];

    control_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    control_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    control_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.7.134");
    control_addr.sin_port = htons(CONTROLPORT);

    return_status = bind(control_sock, (struct sockaddr *) &control_addr, sizeof(control_addr));

    //fcntl(control_sock, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

    return_status = listen(control_sock, 1);
    cout << return_status << endl;
    while(1){
        return_status = accept(control_sock, (struct sockaddr *) &control_addr, &control_len);
        cout << return_status << endl;


        return_status = read(return_status,control_message,sizeof(control_message));

        cout << return_status << endl;

    }
}
```

Comment: This is a part of program. I want to set non blocking so the program can enter the next broadcast functions. Basically I want to read the TCP data (if any) and send out UDP data next. Thanks for any further hints

Comment: not to mention the blocking and non-blocking, the most important part is you should `read()` the descriptor **that the `accept()` returns** in the server side.

Comment: Thanks for figuring this out. oh god how i read the return status.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to engage in non-blocking socket programming you have to understand that read() is going to return -1 with errno set to EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK when there is nothing to read, and use select() to tell you when it won't.

NB 4 is a valid socket FD in Unix, Solaris, HP-UX, AIDA, Linux, ...